# Bullet points appearing next to images

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having a problem with bullet points appearing alongside images on this site: http://docomomo-uk.co.uk/

I've tried using this code based on other posts with similar issues:

```
div#featured-widget-post ul {
list-style-type: none !important;
}
```

but no luck. Any suggestions? All help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you attach some printscreen?

Comment: See both answers below. Both are necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the list surrounded by `ul` tags and you're referencing the element incorrectly with something that isn't there. Wrap your `li` item with `ul`

after you wrap your elements correctly, reference it as such...:

```css
.featured-widget-post ul li {
     list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, feitla. That's taken away the bullet points on the home, but also the rest of the site. Do I have the correct element reference? Thanks again

Comment: Then you will need to target that particular list (the 3 boxes more specifically). Give the `li's` a class name e.g. `class="home-highlights"` and then target those with the css `li.home-highlights {list-style-type:none;}`

Answer (score 2):

Check with

```
.featured-widget-post li{
    list-style-type: none !important;
}
```

1. You use id selector instead of class selector.
2. You don't have `ul` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

.featured-widget-post li {
       list-style: none;
    }

Your code wasn't working because .featured-widget-post is a class (always preceded by a dot (.)) and not an id (preceded by a pound symbol (#)) - and your li tags are not wrapped in a ul.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this css inside your page.

```
  li {
      list-style-type: none;                          docomomo-uk.co.uk #3(line 159)

     }
```